# I am no longer able to drag certain things in Chromium in i3wm

Tags: chromium, i3-window-manager

This is a problem that has started happening over the last week or so. I am no longer able to drag and rearrange tabs with my mouse in chromium when using i3wm. Any time I try to do so it simply creates another Chromium window. Until a week ago I was able to drag tabs without issue. I can still drag tabs in Opera. Additionally, if I use Qtile instead of i3, tab dragging still works as expected.

Additionally, I cannot rearrange my Pandora playlists in Chromium either when using i3wm. Again, this works in Opera. I have not tried this using Chromium in Qtile. Any ideas of what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Several people have asked this question for different platforms over the past week, it appears to be a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1279532